# Installing Yii2: Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I'm installing Yii2 in the way that shows the Getting Started tutorial:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

When I try to access `localhost/YiiTutorial/basic/web` I get this error:

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>   The file or directory to be published does not exist: C:\wamp\www\YiiTutorial\basic\vendor\bower/jquery/dist

In the tutorial says that is nothing to edit... it should work right out of the box... what I'm missing?

If I download the package and place it in the same folder, it works perfect, but I want to install it from composer!

Comment: Did you run 'composer update' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it a recent bug. update your fxp plugin to latest version (1.1.1) and clear composer's cache and try :

```
composer self-update
composer global update
composer update
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside vendor/bower folder it's another one called bower-asset. 
Copy this folder content (some other folders named bootstrap, jquery, etc...) and move them to vender/bower.

Answer (score 0):

In your vendor folder you should rename bower-asset to bower .

OR you can use the following

make sure that you have the following in your composer.json:

- [composer.json](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/composer.json)
- [Other ways](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6402#issuecomment-96234263)

Comment: You should not rename it manually, it's done automatically when Composer Asset Plugin is installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- Mainly if not issue regarding to vendor installation so please give permission to your **/assets** and  **/runtime** folers of your projects and try to run again.

Comment: No, most likely it's related to unexisting folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this kind of problem lately, the issue is in your composer it missing the asset-plugins which allows managing bower and npm package dependencies through Composer. Just run this command, you only need to run this command once for all. You can read the yii2 docs. [Yii2 Installation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```